# libspotify fails with SIGSEGV on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, spotify

I'm writhing a wrapper around native *libspotify.so* (*Spotify* library for Android). And I get this when call **sp_session_starred_create**:

```
A/libc(26182): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 26182 
I/DEBUG(34): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG(34): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.1.1/JRO03E/403059:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG(34): pid: 26182, tid: 26182, name: UNKNOWN 
I/DEBUG(34): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
...
I/DEBUG(34): backtrace:
I/DEBUG(34):     #00  pc 0011fc40  /data/data/.../lib/libspotify.so
I/DEBUG(34):     #01  pc 000e1e58  /data/data/.../lib/libspotify.so
...
D/Zygote(37): Process 26182 terminated by signal (11)
```

The same problem when I call **sp_search_create** or **sp_session_playlistcontainer**.

This is contents of tracefile (I have removed some repeating sp_session_process_events):

```
libspotify trace from 12.1.51.g86c92b43 Release Android-arm 

> sp_session_process_events(0x200f40 0xbeba10cc) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_process_events() = 300447
< sp_session_create() = 0
> sp_session_connectionstate(0x200f40) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_connectionstate() = 0
> sp_session_remembered_user(0x200f40 0xbeba12a4 256) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_remembered_user() = 21
> sp_session_relogin(0x200f40) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_relogin() = 0
> sp_session_connectionstate(0x200f40) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_connectionstate() = 1
> sp_session_starred_create(0x200f40) on 0xafd4a828
> sp_session_process_events(0x200f40 0xbeba0e9c) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_process_events() = 693
> sp_session_process_events(0x200f40 0xbeba0e7c) on 0xafd4a828
< sp_session_process_events() = 692
```

I am insured with debug trace that application crashes somewhere in **sp_session_starred_create**.

Did somebody receive these errors? How can I avoid them?

Comment: How are you invoking sp_session_starred_create, exactly?

Comment: This is my code: `jobject pl = NULL;
    sp_session *n_session = get_session_from_object(env, obj);
    sp_playlist *n_pl = sp_session_starred_create(n_session);
    return pl;`**sp_session_starred_create** entered but never returns control flow.

Comment: We're aware of a few issues like this in libSpotify and are looking into them (I work at Spotify).

Comment: And when will be the next version of **libspotify** for Android with this errors fixed?

Comment: Is there an older, more stable version of libspotify available for download?

Comment: how to integrate libspotify in our android app? Please help me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is an issue within libspotify itself, and will hopefully be fixed in the next version of the library (disclaimer: I work at Spotify). I can't comment on when this release will be available. So hang tight!

However, I would advise checking the session object you are passing to `sp_session_starred_create()`, namely by calling `sp_session_connectionstate()` to make sure that everything is sane.

Comment: Hi Nik, is there a way to obtain older more stable versions of the lib?